# Optional element between .*?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to extract an optional element via PCRE from the following example.
I need to pull out the xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx if ActivityID exists.

I'm guessing I need to use lookaheads or the like but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

```
</Level><Task>...<Correlation ActivityID='{xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx}'/><Execution...</Channel>
```

```
This works if the element exists, saving to taco64:
<\/level>(?<taco16>.*?)ActivityID='{(?<taco64>.*)}'(?<taco32>.*?)<Computer>

Being optional drops everything into taco32. 
<\/level>(?<taco16>.*?)(ActivityID='{(?<taco64>.*)}')?(?<taco32>.*?)<Computer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
<\/level>(?:(?<taco16>.*?)(ActivityID='{(?<taco64>.*)}'))?(?<taco32>.*?)<Computer>
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/d4oLiL/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  level>                   'level>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<taco16>                 group and capture to taco16:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of taco16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<taco64>               group and capture to taco64:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ActivityID='{            'ActivityID=\'{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of taco64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }'                       '}\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<taco32>                group and capture to taco32:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of taco32
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <Computer>               '<Computer>'
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you are a life saver. Never needed to mess with non capturing groups before.

Comment: @TimBrigham Just a small correction: my name is Ryszard (Richard in English) :).

Comment: Well, thank thanks again Ryszard. :) Downside to autocorrect eh?